# Limit length of replies to push notifications on iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification, usernotifications

I need to control the length limit of messages sent while replying to a Push Notification received on iOS, so if the message is longer than x characters, shouldn't be sent. I already tried to investigate without success. Is there a way to obtain this behaviour?

Comment: message sent from app after opening notification?